# Does Mapstruct automatically adds a parameter to the request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, mapstruct

I am working on spring boot with graphql implementation. And, I am mapping my pojo request parameters to an internal project with help of mapstruct. I have written my mapper class where I have mapped my request parameters [source] to the target parameters. I have two different request payload in place and parameters will be mapped based on the request body.

Whatever parameters are given in the request, only those parameters should get mapped and should return the mapped request body. But in my case, When I don't send few parameters in the request payload, after mapping parameters those are not sent in the request also gets added in the conversion.

Sample Request1:
{
GetOrder( input : {
orderId: xxxxxx,
orderType: Online
})
}

Sample Request2:
{
GetOrder( input : {
orderId: xxxxxx,
orderType: Online,
user :{
userName: "ABC"
})
}

In this sample, "User" object is required in the request2, where in request1, I am not sending the user object. But when I send request1, this "User" object is also getting added in the request payload as an empty object after the mapping using mapstruct.

Could you someone please guide me on this.? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please share an example of how your mappers are configured?

Comment: Hi @Filip, 
Thanks for your response. I am able to fix the issue. The problem was, because of the data structure I have. In the above example, In request2, the "User" object has other pojo's mapped to it. For example "User" pojo has "Product" pojo associated with it. When I send the "Product" Pojo details in the graphql request, even though I explicitly not mentioned as "User" pojo, but internally in my target, the "Product" Pojo is tightly coupled with "User". I have modified my GraphQL query structure in a correct way and it works without any issues.